# If I add this code, the ::after scaling will start from some pixels higher

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an effect that when input gets focus the label will go down & change font-size.

But If I add this code below, the `::after` [scaling](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZpMMG)  will start from some pixels higher:

```
input:focus + label > span {
  font-size: 11px;
  bottom: -30px;
}
```

If I [exclude](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdowwV) it, then it will scale properly.

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Seems that the problem is with margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and found this ..

If you remove the `font-size` from this ..

```
input:focus+label>span {
        /*font-size: 11px;*/
        bottom: -30px;
    }
```

Your code is working. If you add this `font-size`, The ::after element is taking the height of the label which is the font size. So the solution is to increase the height of the element. I tried using padding-bottom and it is working for me.

like this ..

```
input:focus+label>span {
        font-size: 11px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        bottom: -30px;
    }
```

Hope this solves your problem.